# Is there way to change font size in putty using the wheel in mouse or contrl +/- key?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, terminal, fonts, putty

I love using Putty as a ssh terminal in Window. But what I don't like about it is that it doesn't allow me to change font using shortcut or a mouse. Is there a way(or plugin) to change the font size in putty using the wheel in mouse or contrl +/- key just as in other applications such as Mac Terminal, Chrome,etc?

Thanks

Comment: You can do this in the default Cygwin terminal (mintty), which incidentally is based on bits of PuTTY.

Comment: For how to do it from configuration before launching: https://askubuntu.com/questions/821527/increase-font-size-of-putty

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, there isn't. Fonts have to be configured before starting the session or during the session with a long list of actions (access the window system menu - change settings - window - appearance).

However in a derived project called [ExtraPuTTY](http://www.extraputty.com) this function (ctrl + mousewheel up/down) is available in latest development snapshot ("ExtraPuTTY 0.28 (Ind 16) snapshot version")

Answer (score 4):

You can alternatively use AutoHotKey with this script. This isn't exactly a *quiet* way but it works. The shortcuts are Ctrl+Alt+= to increase the size, and Ctrl+Alt+- to decrease the size. If you want Ctrl +/- keys, just remove exclamation marks.

```
ChangeFontSize(Direction="Down") {
    nIndex := 15;
    WinGet, hWnd, ID, ahk_class PuTTY
    hSysMenu := DllCall("GetSystemMenu", "UInt", hWnd, "UInt", False)
    nID := DllCall("GetMenuItemID", "UInt", hSysMenu, "UInt", nIndex)
    PostMessage, 0x112, nID, 0, , ahk_id %hWnd%
    SendInput {Shift Down}{Tab}{Shift Up}a{LAlt Down}n{LAlt Up}{LAlt Down}s{LAlt Up}{%Direction%}{Enter}{LAlt Down}a{LAlt Up}
}

#IfWinActive ahk_class PuTTY
^!=::
ChangeFontSize()
return

#IfWinActive ahk_class PuTTY
^!-::
ChangeFontSize("Up")
return
```

This was tested only on Windows 8.1 using PuTTY 0.62 (the vanilla one from the primary website). You may have to adjust nIndex value, which is 0-based and includes dividers, if your system menu looks different from what I have. If you're using a different version of PuTTY or a derivative then you may also have change the sequence of shortcut keys in the script. Make it work and enjoy.

This is what my PuTTY system menu looks like: [PuTTY system menu on Windows 8.1](https://private.michaelhan.net/putty_system_menu.png)

Comment: Nice job! Pretty clever use of macros

Comment: It would have been helpful to add the image into your answer itself (in SO instead of adding an external link) since the link is now HTTP 404. Also it would help if you could add details on how and where to use this script.

Answer (score 3):

Although PuTTY doesn't by default support scroll to resize, [PuTTY Tray](https://puttytray.goeswhere.com/) does. That product maintains a fork of PuTTY with enhancements and bug fixes not found in the traditional version. I prefer it because they use GitHub for collaborative contributions.

Comment: Unfortunately, as of 2020-08-24, the latest release for PuTTYTray is `p0.67-t029` from 2016-06-26. The project is essentially 'dormant' (https://github.com/FauxFaux/PuTTYTray/issues/278). However, I found KiTTY (http://www.9bis.net/kitty/) which is currently active and has been closely tracking PuTTY development for the last two years. It's at version `v0.74.0.4` from 2020-08-12 and it has font zoom on Ctrl+Mouse Wheel and plenty of other features. I just tested the zoom function and it works. I can't vouch for the overall stability (I need more testing time).

Comment: @PetruZaharia Just what I was looking for. Do you mind converting your comment to an answer ?

Answer (score 1):

At least on Windows 7 I increase/decrease the font size by holding `Ctrl` and scrolling the mouse wheel while in active Putty session

Answer (score -3):

I don't change the font size, but I make Mac Terminal bigger or smaller, with the following keys:
`⌘+`
`⌘-`

Comment: Please read the question. This is irrelevant since OP asked about PuTTY. Noone talked about terminal.